# excel vba range row from variable

Tags: vba, excel, range

I need to get ranges from pre-set columns and a row from a variable. If i try to get this range by hand everything works. How do i get the same range using the variable?
How do i get from:

```
Dim j As Integer
j = 20

MsgBox Union(Sheets("Temp").Range("H10:H20"), _
             Sheets("Temp").Range("K10:K20")).Address
```

... to something like this: (only that it works?)

```
MsgBox Union(Sheets("Temp").Range("H10:H" & j ), _
             Sheets("Temp").Range("K10:K" & j)).Address
```

Comment: What's wrong with that code - looks ok to me?

Comment: This seems to work correctly for me. What error are you getting?

Comment: SJR I got myself a trial of MS Office for my home PC just to see if that works for me too... i think my computer at work is cursed. 
Mark.R right now i get no error. But let's wait till i get back to work on monday.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim j As Long
    j = 20

    MsgBox Union(Sheets(1).Range("H10:H" & j), _
                 Sheets(1).Range("K10:K" & j)).Address

End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Did the `As long` fix it or the `Option Explicit` did? Can't test now. I'm at home.

Comment: Well, honestly, I think that your solution was working as well. But in VBA, it is not a good idea to use integers at all. And Option explicit is a good practice.

Comment: Got myself a trial of MS Office at home. My original code works for me here. I have no idea wth is wrong at work... will find out on monday.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking is how you change j (20) into a dynamic variable? if so, something like this will do it:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim j As Long
    j = Range("H10").End(xlDown).Row

    MsgBox Union(Sheets(1).Range("H10:H" & j), _
                 Sheets(1).Range("K10:K" & j)).Address

End Sub
```

Please note: it there's an empty cell in the H column then `j` will be the row immediately above it - a work-around this would be `j = Range("H" & Columns("H:H").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: I do not want `j` to become a range or anything else. I want the range to be **based** on `j`. Gaps in rows don't matter. Also j'th row is not last row.

Comment: @InnerBushman So you want the user to input the j'th row rather than it be hardcoded?

Comment: the `j` will be taken from some other function as a result of sorts. Based on some actions user will take, my code will come up with an integer and pass it in `j` to my function. But first i wanted to write my function and test it before integrating it into bigger whole.

Comment: Then you're original code should work - I've updated my answer to show you my executed code. The only thing I can think of if the scope of `j` is local instead of global (which you need if it's coming from another function.. Have you stepped through and checked if j has *any* value?

Comment: for now `j` is declared inside this function. I've tested my code at home with a trial of MS Office and it works... will check wth is wrong with the one at work on monday. My work PC must be cursed cause i get more of issues like this one where everything works everywhere else but not on my computer. :P